# Currency Setup options are all disabled

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, currency, multicurrency, currency-rates

Not on staging, but on my local instance of magento, logged in as the admin user I created during installation, I am unable to configure any options related to currency, as they are disabled. Is there an option to enable these features that I am missing? The "Use system value" checkboxes are disabled, so I cannot uncheck them.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should some issue on global view, So as of now;

Kindly switch to `Store view` and then hope you can change the fields values.

Cheers!